# Windows Phone 7 Silverlight using session

Tags: c#, silverlight, session, windows-phone-7, session-variables

I am creating a Windows 7 mobile Silverlight project. I use Rest api for authentication using a class say **Authentication**. I get an authentication token as a response and I assign it to a class property **AuthToken** because I need to use this in different places. Is there any way to store this AuthToken in session or any thing else. Because I did not find any session example in wp7. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not finding any session examples because WP7 doesn't have session as far as I know. You should be able to use Isolated Storage to keep your AuthToken around. Bear in mind, however, that it wont expire after a certain amount of time like you'd expect with a session.

See the following or google search Isolated Storage for examples:
http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/all-about-wp7-isolated-storage-store-data-in-isolatedstoragesettings

Hope it helps. I haven't done a great deal of WP7 development, but I'm familiar with Silverlight.

Comment: I am using the above code. but when i get this value in any other class, it does not load the saved value

Answer (score 5):

If you want temporary session storage (the life of the app including when a user uses the back button to return to your app) then you can use **Phone State**.  The Phone State is similar to Session State in ASP.NET. It is just a dictionary of (serializable) objects with string keys and is not maintained across launches of your app, but it is restored when your app is navigated to from the Back Stack.

Here is an example of it's use to restore some custom object named myObject:

```
private CustomObject myObject;

protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs args)
{
    //Save to State when leaving the page
    PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["myObject"] = myObject;
    base.OnNavigatedFrom(args);
}

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs args)
{
    if (PhoneApplicationService.Current.State.ContainsKey("myObject"))
    {
        //Restore from State
        myObject = (CustomObject)PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["myObject"];
    }
    else
    {
        //No previous object, so perform initialization
        myObject = new myObject();
    }
}
```

If you need to store settings across all instances of your app then look into [IsolatedStorageSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) which is perfect for this. There are other options depending on your needs ([Charles Petzold has a free eBook with some great examples](http://charlespetzold.com/phone/index.html)).

---

Not sure why the above code didn't work for you, but another option is to use an app property which is saved using IsolatedStorageSettings.  Here is an example:

In your App.xaml.cs:

```
    public bool VibrationOn { get; set; }

    private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
    {
        LoadSettings();
    }

    private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        LoadSettings();
    }

    private void Application_Deactivated(object sender, DeactivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        SaveSettings();
    }

    private void Application_Closing(object sender, ClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        SaveSettings();
    }

    private void LoadSettings()
    {
        IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

        bool vo;
        if (settings.TryGetValue<bool>("VibrationOn", out vo))
            VibrationOn = vo;
        else
            VibrationOn = true;
    }

    private void SaveSettings()
    {
        IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
        settings["VibrationOn"] = VibrationOn;
    }
```

You can then access this property anywhere in your application by using this code:

```
    if (Application.Current.VibrationOn)
    {
        VibrateController.Default.Start(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200));
    }
```

Comment: I am using the above code. but when i get this value in any other class, it does not load the saved value. It only works when i use break points

Comment: @Muhammad Zeeshan not sure why the page state didn't work for you. It's been fine for me in the limited ways I've used it.  I have updated my answer with an additional example you may find works better for your situation.  If you need the value to expire you can also store a datetime object and check it in the `LoadSettings` method. Another option would be to not call the `LoadSettings`/`SaveSettings` methods in the Application Opening/Closing events so that these values return to defaults when the application is launched anew (but retain them with the back state)

Comment: Thank you so much for the response.I used schummbo's answer.It worked in my situation. I have up voted you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you only want it for the lifetime of the current application instance:

The simplest answer is to store it as a static property instead of an instance property.

The simple answer is to store it as a property of your Application class (App.xaml.cs).  Then you can access it anywhere using ((App)(Application.Current)).Token

The less simple, but probably better answer would be store it in a ViewModel property, which you could then access via a ViewModel locator - take a look at MVVM Light for examples.

In all of these cases you'll need to take into account Tombstoning, to restore it if the user hits Start and then Back (for example).