# how to access MainPage element from another class?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

What is the best way to access MainPage element from another class?
For example, I have a class 'BusinessLogic' from where I would like to set ListOfPersonsListBox.IsEnabled = true;

Comment: Business logic should not be setting GUI attributes directly. The view should pull changes from a bound property. If you switch to an MVVM model that will become clearer. The issue then becomes "how do my business logic classes see a shared MVVM model?".

Answer (score 0):

One way I'd do this is to use the `App` class and defined a static property that I'd sent and then when I hit the `OnNavigatedTo` method on my MainPage I can pick up the value and set the desired Control property to it's new value.

There is also a `PhoneApplicationService.Current.State`, this post explains how to use it quite well:
[Windows Phone 7 Silverlight using session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991604/windows-phone-7-silverlight-using-session)