# How to maintain session in window phone 8

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I dn't how to maintain session window phone .some one blog said  window phone have not support session.they said u can use **isolated storage** . it's possible to store vale in isolated storage to transfer from one page to another?.

If any way to create session then provide me example

Answer (score 0):

These might help you. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff402541(v=vs.105).aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh821020.aspx

it is possible to get the values from the Isolated Storage in any page within the same App

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying it to implement for the `login` functions?

If so this might be helpful:

[How to implement session-time out in a WP app](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_implement_session-time_out_in_a_WP_app)

Or else as @CharithS mentioned you could still go for the `Isolated Storage`!

[Windows Phone 7 Silverlight using session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991604/)

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use isolated storage here is sample to create isolates setting in app launch event

```
  if (!settings.Contains("mobileNumber"))
        {
            settings.Add("mobileNumber", "0");
        }
```

and than to add number to it use this

```
     //watever you want here in string     
    IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["mobileNumber"] = mobileNumber.Text;
```

and to call it use this

```
string aa =IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["mobileNumber"]
```

you can use this logic to implement sessions in your app, but how to utilize is up to you